# How to run a function using "onclick" in JS "setAttribute"?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

Please see my code here: https://repl.it/@AliMosallaei1/Just-A-Test (it uses localStorage and has a lot of parts so I can't really put it in the SO sandbox)

When you add a class and click on the Name of the class, it should execute the `edit()` function in `grade.js`. However, instead, it is throwing a TypeError, saying `edit is not a function`. What could be causing this issue?

EDIT: The file that needs help is the `grade.js`, just to clarify. The major things to look at are the `edit(i)` function and the big `for` loop.

Comment: Kindly refer to this [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer should be on the comment section but I don't have the enough reputation.
Try renaming your "edit()" function to "edit2()" or something else, this should work.